# Build an object dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create an object dynamically in typescript / javascript. I have an array `reqParam` in an object env that might look like this: `env = {reqParams : ['fromTime', 'toTime']}` and it is passed to my initialising function to build an obect dynamically

`const myObject = _initObject(env.reqParams);`

I've started the function, but I can't figure out how to get the key and values into the new object properly.

```
private _initObject(raqParams: any) {
    let requestTemplate = {
      bodyjson : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
      "cognitoUserId": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub", 
      "cognitoUserEmail": "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
    };
    reqParams.forEach(param => {
      // build new item
      let templateEntry = "$input.params('`param`')";
      // Put new item into object
      requestTemplate[`param`] = templateEntry;
    });
}
```

Hopefully, you can see what I'm trying to achieve. For example, here's the desired outcome for 2 reqParams : fromTime and toTime:

```
      {
        bodyjson : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",       
        "fromTime": "$input.params('fromTime')",
        "toTime": "$input.params('toTime')",
        "cognitoUserId": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub",
        "cognitoUserEmail": "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 typo and 2 fixes and it works, like so:

```js
const _initObject = (reqParams) => {
    let requestTemplate = {
      bodyjson : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
      "cognitoUserId": "$context.authorizer.claims.sub", 
      "cognitoUserEmail": "$context.authorizer.claims.email"
    };
    reqParams.forEach(param => {
      // build new item
      let templateEntry = `$input.params('${param}')`;
      // Put new item into object
      requestTemplate[param] = templateEntry;
    });
    return requestTemplate;
}

console.log(_initObject(['fromTime', 'toTime']));
```

Comment: Greate work! We're almost there!!! A few mods since I'm working in typescript. I had to write `const _initObject = ((reqParamsArray: string[])`. And there's one error still due to the requestTemplate[param] : `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type ... No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ bodyjson: string; cognitoUserId: string; cognitoUserEmail: string; }'.ts(7053)`

Comment: you may try to set `((param: string) => {`

Comment: YES. That is actually what I did. Also need to use `let requestTemplate: {[index: string]:any} = {` and `(reqParamsArray: string[]) =>` You could edit those into your answer maybe?

Comment: i could but then the output will not work

Comment: Have a look at this. Let me know if it makes sense: https://cutt.ly/5xeLfPs

Comment: it looks ok, one question only, why try/catch?

Comment: so it still works if options is undefined. try it without defining options, it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
reqParams.forEach(param => {
      // build new item
      let templateEntry = `$input.params('${param}')`;
      // Put new item into object
      requestTemplate[param] = templateEntry;
    });
```

js use `${}` for the string interpolation

```
key = 'dynamic'
object[key]  = value
```

will give you a object of `{'dynamic':value}`